# fpm v.1.11.0 vs inclusion of /usr/lib/.build-id files

Tags: rpmbuild, deb

New to using fpm I’m trying to package some config files and a few binaries (from [source: dir](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/dir.html)), eg. no building from sources.
When I get a package it seems to include symlinks from under /usr/lib/.build-id pointing to the binaries in the package.

How may I avoid such symlinks in my pacakages?

TIA!

Comment: presumably it's rpmbuild that automatically add these build-id, so seems I can't use fpm's --exclude PATTERN to avoid such.

Comment: Haven't found a way to ask rpmbuild to exclude build-id symlinks and because I'm repacking multiple packages which has the same binary content named differently their build-id hash values conflicts on install :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding these options to fpm did the trick:

--rpm-tag '%define _build_id_links none'
--rpm-tag '%undefine _missing_build_ids_terminate_build'

thanks to info found [here](https://gnu.wildebeest.org/blog/mjw/2017/06/30/fedora-rpm-debuginfo-improvements-for-rawhidef27/)